# How to bypass cloudflare using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, parsing, header, cloudflare

I create a ChromeDriver in c #, I just go to the site with CloudFlare, I manually solve the captcha, but it gives me a new one and won't let me go. I tried to use solutions, via using ChromeDriver's launch arguments, but it didn't help. I am using the newest version of ChromeDriver and Selenium.

Comment: You'd need to do this at the server/service level.  You can just turn off bot-detection in your cloudflare services.